# Ubuntu 18.04 - installed gnome-shell-common by mistake now no UI

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management

When doing `apt upgrade` I was told package `gnome-shell-common` is kept back. I tried to install and although I was warned I admit I confirmed the dependencies to break.
Now I can not get event to the login window.
Please advise how to get my beloved Ubuntu Gnome desktop back.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work as simple as:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

---

Some recommendations:

1. Before installation or upgrading of any software from repositories always update package lists with `sudo apt-get update`.
2. If `sudo apt-get upgrade` fails because of held packages or broken dependencies - try to switch to the *Main server* mirror, update package lists and retry. In very seldom situations local mirror may be non-syncronized.
3. I don't recommend to install packages with `dpkg -i` - such method is a last resort and may be used only by very experienced users (they know how to fix if it fails). **Do not try to fix dependencies by hand if you are newbie**. Use the power of APT instead - one simple command `sudo apt-get install -f` will do all the work for correct dependency resolution. If it fails you can use more advanced tool - [`aptitude`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/aptitude-curses.8.html) - its `sudo aptitude install -f` will try to fix deep problems.
4. If you forced to install single deb-package - use `sudo apt install ./*.deb` for automatic resolution of the dependencies.
5. For better understanding of software and package management consider to [read documentation on Ubuntu site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoftwareManagement).

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I did the same mistake as Peter Loef trying to follow some older guides and fix the dependencies, but in fact it was simple like that

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: So `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` fixes the problem, as can be seen in the comment for the accepted answer. Well isn't that nice :s

---

I did the same thing. Maybe just installing `ubuntu-desktop` again will fix it, it wasn't the first thing I tried, but in case it doesn't here's what I had to do.

The problem here is that the `gnome-shell-common` that was installed, is for Ubuntu 18.04.2, which is why it uninstalled all the gnome stuff for Ubuntu 18.04.1. Now, I couldn't just reinstall `gnome-shell`, because the gnome-shell it now wants to install, is also the one for 18.04.2, including the 18.04.2 dependencies. But Ubuntu won't let you do that, because older versions of those dependencies are still in use.

So what you need to do is install the 18.04.1 versions of both gnome-shell and `gnome-shell-common` manually. Download them both from the Ubuntu site and install them using `sudo dpkg -i <filename>`. These are your files, usually the amd64 one:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gnome-shell and
https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/gnome-shell-common

Now when you try to install `gnome-shell`, it will give you a list of all the unmet dependencies that were uninstalled when you installed `gnome-shell-common`. You can install all of them using `sudo apt install <package names>`. There were close to 15. After you've done this, I think install `gnome-shell-common` first, and then gnome-shell.

Now, `gdm3` and `ubuntu-desktop` are also gone, so install those as well using `sudo apt install <package names>`, and your Gnome desktop should be back. You'll probably have lost your settings though, but I'm not sure about that.

I don't understand how this could have happened. Why was it an option to install this `gnome-shell-common` from Ubuntu 18.04.2? It cost me about six hours to fix this problem. I'm glad I might have at least helped someone else with fixing it.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I was trying to do it exactly the same way as you did, but gave up because it did not felt to be the right way. I am anyway happy you were able to fix your installation. The issue is, in some guides it is recommended to install package that was hold back so I now feel this is a "no no" now...

Comment: Thanks David! I'm never installing a held back package again unless I get a personal email from Canonical telling me my house will catch on fire if I don't install it.

Comment: @PeterLoef you have written very interesting analysis. But FYI Ubuntu 18.04.2 currently does not have [release date](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseSchedule). So this assumption is not fully true. Also I don't recommend to install packages with `dpkg -i` - such method is a last resort and may be used only by very experienced users (they know how to fix if it fails). If you forced to install single deb-package - use `sudo apt install ./*.deb` instead. **And do not forget to update package lists with `sudo apt-get update` before any software installation or upgrade.**

Comment: Thanks @N0rbert! As for the 18.04.2 part, the version number for the held back gnome-shell-common package, is for Ubuntu 18.04.2, and the unmet depenency that the gnome-shell needed that I tried to install using apt, was also the 18.04.2 version. And when I did sudo apt list --upgradable after sudo apt update, the gnome-shell and gnome-shell-common I could install had 18.04.2 right there in the version number. It's also already possible to download lots of 18.04.2 packages from the Ubuntu site I referenced above. I'll be sure to keep that in mind about not using dpkg -i!

Comment: @PeterLoef I have just read full version number and understood what do you mean. I do not know why they use this numbers. But right - the newest version is `3.28.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.2`, while previous was `3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`. I'm not sure it really related to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, or it is just increment of the last digit :) Also problem may be caused if local mirror was not synced ontime.